# Why does 100% equal 150 pixels?

Tags: html, css, svg

The following code results in a table that 150 pixels tall. Why 150? Is this an SVG quirk or something more general?

https://jsfiddle.net/cc9tyw5v/31/

```
<table class="root" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <svg class="root-symbol" viewBox="0 0 5 6.5" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height:100%;background-color:lightgreen;">
        <text x="0" y="6.5" font-size="9px">a</text>
      </svg>
    </td>
    <td><span style="font-size:2em;background-color:lightblue">I would expect it to be as tall as this span</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)

> SVG isn't (just) an image. SVG is a document. The default size for HTML replaced elements will be used: 300px wide, **150px tall.** This applies for `<img>`, `<object>` or `<iframe>`. The default **300x150** size also applies to inline `<svg>` elements within HTML documents, but that's a relatively recent consensus from the HTML5 specifications: other browsers will by default expand inline SVG to the full size of the viewport—equivalent to width: 100vw; height: 100vh; — which is the default size for SVG files that are opened directly in their own browser tab. Internet Explorer cuts the difference, using width of 100% and **height of 150px for images and inline SVG.**

Comment: That is very valuable information and answers the question that I posed in the subject. Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I want, which is to have the SVG expand vertically to be the same height as the tallest cell in the table?

Comment: @PavelGrinfeld preservespectRatio <> none

Comment: Then it won't stretch vertically when the content grows.

Answer (score -1):

The span you are attempting to fit the height of is not the parent of the SVG. It is a sibling, and therefore `height:100%` will not fit its height.